# Openssl output file permission

Tags: linux, openssl, file-permissions

I currently have a script that runs a openssl like the following:

```
VerbosePrint `openssl req -config "$certificate_authority_openssl_file" -newkey rsa -x509 -out "$certificate_authority_certificate"`
```

Where
`$certificate_authority_openssl_file` is a configuration file
`$certificate_authority_certificate` is the self signed output.

The problem is that i don't want the outputed files to have `0644` file permissions but i can't seem to generate them without being created unexposed. I have made the folder in which this files are located, `0700`.

My question is if it is acceptable that certificate and private keys files have 0644 permissions in a `0700` directory. If it is not, how can i force openssl to generate the files with the correct permissions by default as it seems to ignore the parent directory permissions.

If you need a template of the configuration file please ask.

Thank you
Paulo Neves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the umask command to filter the permissions.
Usually the default umask is 0022, thus your file is being created with 0644.

Try to use umask 0077 in your script before the openssl command. That should do the trick.

Please check the man for umask for more details.

Comment: That did it. I actually didn't know about that possibility. Thank you alot.